# Compute the residue of $\frac{\sin 2z-2 \sin z}{\sin z(\sin z-z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute the resuide of $\dfrac{\sin (2z)-2 \sin(z)}{\sin (z)(\sin (z)-z)}$ at $z=0$.

The method of Laurent Series doesn't work with this due to the multiplication and divisions by various forms of $\sin z$ (so getting a single laurent series seems impossible with my current understanding. And I don't quite understand how to find an $S$ such that I could try the Residue Theorem, much less how to do the integral in it.

What doesn't help is that Wolfram Alpha claims that the $a^{-1}$ value of the Laurent series is $6$ (implying the residue equals 6), whereas it claims the residue is $0$ with a different calculator that claims to be specificly for residues.

Comment: $$\frac{\sin (2 z)-2 \sin (z)}{\sin (z) (\sin (z)-z)}\simeq \frac{\color{red}{6}}{z}-\frac{z}{5}-\frac{z^3}{2100}+\frac{z^5}{63000}+O\left(z^6\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

No, Laurent series actually works here. Note that the residue is defined by the coefficient of the $\frac{1}{z-z_0}$ term in the Laurent series, so in principle, Laurent series can be used to find residues for all cases (as long as it exsits).

By doing a series expansion at $z=0$ on numerator and denominator, we can see

$$\sin(2z)-2\sin(z)\sim -z^3$$

$$\sin(z)(\sin(z)-z)\sim -\frac{1}6z^4$$

So $z=0$ is a simple pole actually, and the residue is $6$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{\sin (2z)-2 \sin(z)}{\sin (z)(\sin (z)-z)}=\dfrac{2\sin (z)\cos(z)-2 \sin(z)}{\sin (z)(\sin (z)-z)}=\dfrac{2\cos(z)-2}{\sin (z)-z}\\
\text{We know that}\\
\cos(z)\sim1-\frac{1}{2!}z^2\qquad \sin(z)\sim z-\frac{1}{3!}z^3\\
\text{So...}\\
\dfrac{2-z^2-2}{z-\frac{1}{6}z^3-z}=\dfrac{-z^2}{-\frac{1}{6}z^3}=\frac{6}{z}\\
$$
So the residue is $6$.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even look at your answer in details before wrinting my long essay as an answer, but using the double angle formula for sine is a great touch, didn't think of that at all. That would have made my answer considerably shorter. Oh well.

Comment: @Sellerie ahaha thank you

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let us first look at the numerator and denominator functions seperately. Both are $0$ at $z_0=0$, so we are looking at a singularity. Whether it's removable or a pole is not yet clear. But we can compute:
$$\sin(z)=z\cdot f(z)$$
for some holomorphic $f$ that doesn't vanish at $z_0=0$. In fact, we can even compute $f$ at $0$ as follows:
$$f(0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin(z)-\sin(0)}{z-0}=\sin'(0)=\cos(0)=1$$
With this we can easily see the following:
$$\frac{\sin(2z)-2\sin(z)}{\sin(z)(\sin(z)-z)}=\frac{2zf(2z)-2zf(z)}{zf(z)(zf(z)-z)}=\frac{2z(f(2z)-f(z))}{zf(z)(z(f(z)-1))}=\frac{2}{f(z)}\frac{(f(2z)-f(z))}{(z(f(z)-1))}$$
The first factor is holomorphic at $z_0=0$, but the second still needs some simplification. Again we have several zeros, at least one in the numerator, at least two in the denominator (since $f(0)-1=0$). You may wonder how we can even continue from here since we know so little about $f$. But in fact we can find out quite a lot about $f$ as follows:
$$f'(0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{f(z)-1}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{zf(z)-z}{z^2}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin(z)-z}{z^2}$$
Here we remember the series representation of $\sin$:
$$f'(0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{z^2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}-z\right)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=\lim_{z\to 0}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{z^{2k-1}}{(2k+1)!}=\lim_{z\to 0}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+3)!}=-\frac{1}{3!}$$
So the numerator still has a zero, but what multiplicity? Easily computed, let's find the derivative of the numerator: $2f'(2z)-f'(z)$, which evaluates at $0$ to $-2/3!+1/3!\neq 0$. The same argument as above with $\sin$ applies - we only have a simple zero, thus the numerator can be written as $f(2z)-f(z)=z\cdot g(z)$ for some holomorphic $g$ such that $g(0)\neq 0$ (what is $g(0)$? We just computed it to be...?)
Lastly we can see that the denominator has one more zero. It is given be $z^2 h(z)$ for some holomorphic $h$ such that $h(0)\neq 0$. Can you compute $h(0)$ yourself?

Now, putting everything together:
$$\frac{\sin(2z)-2\sin(z)}{\sin(z)(\sin(z)-z)}=\frac{2}{f(z)}\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}\frac{1}{z}.$$
If we consider the first functions as a power series, they are given by
$$\frac{2}{f(z)}\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k,\quad\text{where }a_0\neq 0\text{ (why?)}$$
Do you see how you can compute the residue of the full thing here?

This was a very long answer which could have (and already has) been answered in a few short statements, but I wagered those statements wouldn't tell you much, if you didn't know the theory behind them. So I gave you a way which actually explains how to obtain those statements. I hope it is helpful and you can figure out the missing details I left open.